# how to patch git completion that is missing the difftool command

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, git-config, zsh-completion

My system's git autocompletion is pretty good, but lacks completion of at least `git difftool` and `git diffmerge`. I mean that if I type `git diff<TAB>` on my prompt what I get is the following:

```
$ g diff<TAB>
diff         -- show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc.
diff-files   -- compare files in the working tree and the index
diff-index   -- compare content and mode of blobs between index and repository
diff-stages  -- compare two "merge states" in the index file
diff-tree    -- compare the content and mode of blobs found via two tree objects
```

See? No `difftool` or `diffmerge` there. I have to type them all over to the end in order to use them, or create some git alias, which I don't want.

Is there a way to patch the default git completion configuration to add support for these two commands? Where is the default git completion script? Can I modify it, or better yet, patch it in my own `.zshrc` or something so I don't have to mess up with the system original?

In case someone wants to know, I'm using zsh 4.3.11 on Mac Lion with the latest oh-my-zsh installed as well. My git is installed from homebrew and it's version 1.8.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

git completion is done by an autoloading function `_git`. You can override it.

1. download the latest version of `_git` from [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_git) (use the raw link to get it).
2. put it in a `$fpath` directory coming first than the path of shipped scripts. `print -l $fpath` will show you the list, and you can add one to the front by e.g. adding `fpath=($HOME/.zsh/Completion $fpath)` to your zshrc. Be sure the change of `$fpath` comes before `compinit`.

Comment: Neither the latest completion file above nor the [latest one shipped in git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh) contain support for `diffmerge` yet, only `difftool`.  Good opportunity for someone who wants to get a patch into zsh and/or git.